# Custom CSS to remove specific margins on Wordpress page

Tags: css, wordpress, margin, inspect

Recently I've made a new `Wordpress` crew page for my team. I'm using the visual composer plugin to put it all together. Unfortunately, The Wordpress theme adds a margin between the two sides that I cannot remove using visual composer. ([see here](https://ibb.co/ek75cd))

After using inspect element in Safari I found the line that creates the margin ([see here](https://ibb.co/bVWZLy)). After deleting the line it looks  ([like this](https://ibb.co/k3LfSd)).

My main question is: what is the best way to remove this margin? I'm afraid that jumping into the source code will mess up the website because the margin is part and connected to so many classes, maybe even on other pages?

Additional question: After deleting the margin in the inspector tool it creates white space on the right. I tried to find a specific page width or something similar but without success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a link to this page please?

Comment: maybe putting live this page would help us a little more.

Comment: I'm sorry the page was still on concept mode. I published it for you guys to have a look! http://www.cameradenmedia.nl/gif-test-2/

Answer (score 0):

Consider this aproach,
Visual editor plugin lets you put custom css on every page you create, so[image]

[image]

What now? you need to target a really specific selector that you want to modify, you can use Chrome Dev Tools inspector to copy most specific selector for the item you are inspectin, like this:

go to inspect element, find the element with your mouse and right click on it, select copy and copy selector

[image]

it will get you something like this

```
#comment-88140204 > div.comment-text.js-comment-text-and-form > div > span.comment-copy
```

There you go, you can now override any styles for this particular element, not worring about making a mess somewhere else

Hope this helps